# Spring Boot get JSON Error representation in the ErrorController

Tags: java, spring-boot

Spring Boot provides errors in the json format like this:

```
{
  "timestamp": "2019-01-17T16:12:45.977+0000",
  "status": 500,
  "error": "Internal Server Error",
  "message": "Error processing the request!",
  "path": "/endpoint"
}
```

Is it possible for me to obtain this error inside the `ErrorController` and to proceed with it?

```
@Controller
public class CustomErrorController implements ErrorController {

@RequestMapping("/error")
public String handleError(Model model) {
    // how to get json-error here?
    model.addAttribute("resultJson", ?);
    return "error";
  }
}
```

Is it inside the `HttpServletResponse` or maybe something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default `error` attributes are extracted from a `WebRequest` using the `ErrorAttributes` bean.

*Spring* already provided a default implementation of this bean, the `DefaultErrorAttributes` bean.

You can have this bean injected by the container, as any usual bean, to your custom */error* controller implementation so you can use it:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping({"/error"})
public class CustomErrorController extends AbstractErrorController {

    public CustomErrorController(final ErrorAttributes errorAttributes) {
        super(errorAttributes, Collections.emptyList());
    }

    @RequestMapping
    public String handleError(Model model, HttpServletRequest request) {
        Map<String, Object> errorAttributes = this.getErrorAttributes(request, false); // retrieve the default error attributes as a key/value map (timestamp, status, error...)
        // ...
    }

    @Override
    public String getErrorPath() {
        return "/error";
    }
}
```

### Update (by @Igorz)

As of *Spring Boot* version ***2.3.0***

```java
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.AbstractErrorController#getErrorAttributes(HttpServletRequest, boolean, boolean, boolean)
```

has been deprecated in favor of:

```java
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.AbstractErrorController#getErrorAttributes(HttpServletRequest, ErrorAttributeOptions)
```

Static factory `ErrorAttributeOptions.defaults()` can be used as default `ErrorAttributeOptions`  argument of above method.

Comment: Thank you very much. That's it! Just the only note `this.getErrorAttributes(request, false) is Deprecated since 2.3.0 in favor of getErrorAttributes(HttpServletRequest, ErrorAttributeOptions)`. Can be used with the `ErrorAttributeOptions.defaults()`.

Comment: Thanks for the note @IgorZ. I will add it to the response as an update note for future readers.